# Bayesian networks from a table

Tags: self-study, bayesian-network

Could someone help me with question 5.b. I understand that the probability of any of these occuring independently is 0.5 but how do I combine those into a joint distribution function?

Is $0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 0.0625$ correct?

[image]

Edit:

Is it more like this?

$S =$ Spam, $D =$ Dear, $F =$ Free, $H =$ Hot
$$
P(S, D, F, H) = P(S) \cdot P(D | S) \cdot P (F | S, D) \cdot P(H | S, D, F)
$$
Therefore:

[image]

or am I missing something?

Comment: is this homework or self-study? If so, please tag your question accordingly

Comment: exam revision looking at past papers.

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of the problem, I would rather structure the model as a Naive Bayes classifier, i.e. with edges going from Spam to Hot, Free and Dear.  It's a modelling choice of course, but I think it makes more sense given the task at hand.

With this Naive Bayes structure, the joint probability distribution is then simply:

$$
P(Hot, Free, Dear, Spam) = P(Hot \ | \ Spam) \ P(Free \ | \ Spam) \ P(Dear \ | \ Spam) \ P(Spam)
$$